# jQuery(...).colorbox is not a function

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm having trouble initiating colorbox, I'm using Cakephp this is what I'm doing:

The error is:
**TypeError: jQuery(...).colorbox is not a function**

on Head

```
echo $this->Html->script('lib/jquery-1.11.1.min');
echo $this->Html->script('lib/jquery.colorbox');

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('inline_content').colorbox();
            });
</script>
```

on body

```
<div id='inline_content' class="popup" style='height:400px;'>
        <a href="">
            <div class="foto">
                <div class="titlepopup">

                    <img src="img/lightbox.jpg" class="marcas" />
                </div>
            </div>      
        </a>    
    </div>
```

I also looked at the browser and the js are loaded correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisS It says right there, 1.11.1...

Comment: Yep, I miss read that as 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector:

```
jQuery('#inline_content').colorbox();
```

Notice the `#`. It means 'id' in terms of jQuery selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: A wrong selector wouldn't cause a "colorbox is not a function" error.